# What are various effective practices in modularizing the individual features of a mobile app?

Tags: angularjs, git, ionic-framework, architecture, software-design

### Background

While this is *not* a theoretical question, I would like to ask for suggestions on how to best approach the modularization of features of a mobile app.

If it helps, I usually use Ionic for mobile app development, so it would be great if the best practices would work with Ionic, but any general recommendation and suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Ionic is a cross-platform mobile app development framework that supports creating Android and iOS apps using Angular / TypeScript.

### Problem

Let us assume we have an application that lets users register for an account. Upon registration, this application will offer various services to the user, a really wide variety. Let's say the user can receive notifications (both in-app pages and push notifications), receive discount coupons (either from coupons given by the admin using a management dashboard, or via doing things such as achieving a certain amount of steps recorded by the app as a pedometer, etc), and various other features.

Having so many features in an app will make it huge indeed, and since as a software development company, we would like to tailor the app so that it can provide what a client needs, and not provide the other things.

The problem in short becomes something like:

1. What is the best way to separate the different features of an app, make it modular and non-dependent on each-other so that some features can be easily disabled and the others enabled?
2. Is there a way so that the disabled features are not included at all in the resulting compiled app?

### My own idea

The most logical way I can think of right now is to have a core app that includes all features. The features are enabled (shown in the app menu bar) by configuring the app's build `environment` file; for example, setting `coupons: false,` would cause all coupon-related feature to not get enabled most probably by using `if` statements and `ngIf` directives around the app. This core app will have all features enabled by default, but once a client requests for a specific app configuration, a new Git branch will be created from the latest branch, configured to the client's needs, and remain as a separate branch (or project).

However, my boss has complained that "that solution sounds like it's coming from the year 2010, there *has* to be another way," and unfortunately, I can't think of anything better than this. There will definitely also be design changes (like logos, color themes, and layout changes and font size changes) that can never be customized just by changing flags on a build `environment` file (is there? Maybe I'm the one who doesn't know.) so I don't know how to support those by using something 'better than Git'.

### Conclusion

Modularization of an app by implementing various features as modules so that they can easily be enabled or disabled upon client request is probably feasible in some way, but I'm not sure if there is something better than Git in order to facilitate the management of different versions. My boss seems to be expecting it to be as easy as the flick of a switch (and enabling/disabling features can probably be made to be this easy), but attending to the unique needs of the client (text, design, layout, etc differences) is quite hard to do as easily.

I would be really thankful for any suggestions, or ideas on how to approach this scenario.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think that this question might be more suited for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @mnestorov when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat my bad, I didn't check if OP did a cross-post. I thought about migrating the question but I don't have such powers.

Comment: @mnestorov Thank you very much for the suggestion. I would like to also try asking there but I'm not sure how to move the question without cross-posting. I apologize for the inconvenience this has caused. What would be the proper thing for me to do in this case?